# Disable built in display when external is provided in Gnome

Tags: gnome, opensuse, displayport

My laptop has a 4k display. When I plug in my thunderbolt 3 to display port adapter which connects to 3 1920x1200 displays over MST it fails to properly connect because it exceeds the maximum resolution permitted by my GPU.

A -hopeful- solution to this is disabling the built in display and then connecting to the external displays. However, I can't seem to pull it off properly through the display manager and it usually ends in me crashing things.

**Summary:**

Laptop -> Thunderbolt 3 to display port adapter -> 3 1920x1200 displays over MST/Daisy Chaining

I am seeking to disable the built-in display when external displays are detected and reenable it when external displays are unplugged.

[image]

Comment: It's always worked for me in the past through Display Properties. Plug in the monitor and turn it on, detect displays, tell it to turn the panel off, apply, accept.

Comment: Due to resolution constraints this does not work for me. I can only get two external displays working instead of all 3.

Comment: [Don't post screenshots of textual output](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text), paste *the actual text*...

Comment: @jasonwryan I would argue that in this context that is insignificant.

Comment: @Alec I don't care whether the information is significant or not, I just don't want people here thinking that it is acceptable to post screenshots of text.

Comment: @jasonwryan Furthermore: what's acceptable on a service is purely the rules, not opinion. I don't care about the meta, and I don't need to until I'm required to comply by it. I don't care about catering to someone's standard that isn't official. You don't define what's acceptable, maybe your reputation has brought you an ego.

Comment: @Alec - jason's correct, screenshots of terminal output which is just text is discouraged.  Posting screenshots in this manner undermines the indexing that can occur given there's text within the screenshot, making it impossible to be searched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, an `xrandr --listmonitors` shows the displays visible for your X.

For example, you will see these (I have a single-display, you will have multiple):

```
Monitors: 1
 0: +*DVI-0 1920/598x1080/336+0+0  DVI-0
```

Now if I would want to power off my DVI-0 display, I would issue an

```
xrandr --output DVI-0 --off
```

You can get a more detailed list of your display configuration with an `xrandr -q`.

The problem is, that it is a command line tool. Doing this automatically on display connect/disconnect is possible, but in the case of gnome+suse, I don't know, how.

Maybe you will get a more detailed answer for that - if your question wouldn't be closed until that.

Answer (score 2):

Check `autorandr` package. You create set ups and the tool switches between them automatically.